# I was given an important financial pdf document that's been edited. On edited page, instead of a date, it reads "timestamp" - what would cause that?

Tags: pdf

I was given a very highly important financial document that is visually highly edited but it is difficult to prove changes in any type of pdf editor I am told - (I think that is where they were done, a pdf editor maybe, I am not 100% sure), for example, on the one page that is highly doctored, it shows the word - timestamp - where every other place on the document it shows the correct date that is supposed to have been the date that I signed this supposed agreement. What would cause that type of error? I read somewhere that maybe when a document from a company has been edited from it's original form or use, there is some form of security function that might cause the field where the correct date was, to be changed to the default of the word, timestamp.

Is this something that could be software specific? SQL? HTML? If this is the wrong forum for asking this question, please don't kill me, I am doing my best not to get completely screwed and me and my wife are running into dead ends everywhere and I figured this was worth a shot.

Having said that, is there any other way to look into the advanced metadata of the pdf to check for any fraud? We have went down that road too and it seems that it is almost impossible to track "what" was changed other than the original creation date and modification date, which the thresholds are so low for, that doesn't prove any maliciousness. We also do not have the original pdf, from what we can tell, it has been saved multiple times by multiple parties that it is hindering our progress in getting to the truth.

Thank you and god bless!

Comment: The only way to *prove* manipulations is applying a digital signature at the start, i.e. right after document creation, and validating the signature whenever processing the document.

Comment: @KJ *"Do you know if the signing authority is obliged to keep a copy of the original hash request?"* - obligations are up to the local applicable law, so that would depend on the circumstances of the op. If you want to proof that a PDF was in a specific state at a given time, better use a digital time stamp.

Comment: One thing that wasn't mentioned here is that it is possible the document was saved with incremental saves. In that case it may be possible to see information for when each save was done (and even extract previous versions of the document so you can see the differences). No way of knowing that without having the actual document to examine. If the document *was* digitally signed at the start, this is possible as it would also include a flag for software to use incremental saves rather than full saves.